# Golang looping through redis store to delete gorilla sessions

Tags: go, session, session-cookies, gorilla

I am using gorilla sessions.
I have a redis store which has sessions:

**here is a sample one:**

```
"session_UDPTLRXUXTJZMVB2AFWRNJHJQXBR27ZY5KZ7Z3KSIXL6ETQ4KXEIBJA4WEVEQID2WSAFQFKLFOHWYT42PIHUMRNW5RWSS76Z72QS4SI"
```

getting an existing session:

```
store := redisSessionInstance.Store

session, err := store.Get(c.Request(), "session_")
if err != nil {
    return c.String(http.StatusNotAcceptable, "failed getting session")
}
```

on these sessions is stored an id which identifies the owner.

```
session.Values["userID"] = existingUser.ID.Hex()
```

what is the best way to delete all sessions for a user?
I could loop through all the sessions in a for loop and then query the stored value to see if it matches the owners id.

Is there a faster way?

Comment: Unless you build and maintain an index on the side, the only option is to iterate through the sessions stored in Redis.

Comment: Yeah I thought so, it would be nice to add some user id alongside it which would be the user id.